# I am trying to understand the format for the "date" fields in yfinance module

Tags: python, yfinance

I am getting some data with yfinance module and I can't understand the format of some "date" fields.

For example, for the ticket "CAT" I got this values:
"nextFiscalYearEnd" = 1672444800 and "dateShortInterest" = 1623715200
How can I convert this kind of fields into a "normal" date values ?

This is the code:

```
import yfinance as yf

ticker = yf.Ticker("CAT")   

print(ticker.info["nextFiscalYearEnd"],ticker.info["dateShortInterest"])
```

I will be grateful if you can help me!

Answer (score 0):

Those look like UNIX time_t values (a.k.a. "epoch time", the number of non-leap seconds since January 1, 1970 at midnight UTC); it's how modern UNIXlike operating systems keep their system clocks. You can convert such a value into a Python `datetime` with the function `fromtimestamp()` for local time or `utcfromtimestamp()` for UTC. I prefer to see datetimes in ISO 8601 format, which you can get out of a datetime by calling `isoformat()` on it:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime as dt
>>> dt.utcfromtimestamp(1623715200).isoformat()
'2021-06-15T00:00:00'
>>> dt.utcfromtimestamp(1672444800).isoformat()
'2022-12-31T00:00:00'
```

So the two in your question represent midnight at the onset of 15 June 2021 and 31 December 2022.

Comment: Thank you!! That is the solution!